# 'resize' event handler doesn't occur

Tags: jquery, html

I am improving one site now - http://vse-v-nas.com.ua (link just for reproduce steps, if someone wants to look deeper).

Right columns of content:

```
// html
<td id="sidebar-right">...</td>
// css
#sidebar-right {
  width: 209px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

i.e. $('#sidebar-right').width() should be 229px
and **it is in Chrome**, but it has '245px' value in FF 8.0.1 and IE 9.0.3

I don't know why right column width of content is other in FF and IE than in Chrome,
but I would like that image (in top right corner - $('img.header-image')) has the same with as right column below (like in Chrome).

I added script into body before end of tag, in order to set equal width for image and right sidebar.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var $headerImage = $('img.header-image');
    var $rightSidebar = $('#sidebar-right');

    // in this line $rightSidebar.width() is 229px in every browser...

    $rightSidebar.resize(function() {
      // event handler doesn't occur after width changing in IE and FF...
      alert($headerImage.width());
      alert($(this).width());
    });
  });
</script>
```

Event handler doesn't occur, but size is changing after page loading.
Anybody has idea to help me to solve this problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resize handler won't work on divs/elements of the page.  Check out http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin/.  It's a plugin created to handle these types of situations.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the answer above has answered your direct question. As to why it's 245 in Safari and Firefox, it's probably down to the default CSS presumed by different browsers, especially the border-spacing since you're using lots of tables. The inner content being bigger will force the sidebar div to be wider than 229px.

Comment: Hi, David, as I wrote, I am improving this site after previous developer. Anyways, I am going to rewrite it under .NET later. But it should work correct now.